# Rest controller giving 404

Tags: json, spring, web-services, controller, http-status-code-404

Im trying to hit the post controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController
{

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomerController.class);

    @Resource(name = "lookupAddressClient")
    private LookupAddressClient lookupAddressClient;

    @Autowired
    private HssCustomerFacade customerFacade;

    private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping)
    {
        this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpointdoc", method =
    { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public void show(final Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("handlerMethods", this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());
    }

    @Resource(name = "hssB2BCommerceUserFacade")
    protected HssB2BCommerceUserFacade hssB2BCommerceUserFacade;
    private static final String ERROR_MSG = "##### Error in HssB2BCommerceUserFacade.getUserdetailsForHSSTraining()-->";
    private static final String ERROR_MSG_END = "####";


    /* TODO: Need to move this controller to hsscommercewebservice once fix the hsscommerce webservice url issue fixed */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/webservice/userDetails", method =
    { RequestMethod.POST }, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody HSSUserData getUserDetails(@RequestBody final UserCredentials userCredentials,
            final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
....
}
```

Where the getUserDetails() is the method.

The UserCredentials:

```
public class UserCredentials {

    private String userId;
    private String password;
    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserCredentials [userId=" + userId + ", password=" + password
                + "]";
    }

Im using PostMan client:
```

I hit the URL : https://localhost:8011/webservice/userDetails

My headers: Accept = application/json
Content-type = application/json

My JSON Body in the request:

```
{
    "userCredentials": {
    "userId": "asdnasd",
    "password": "nasdkask"
  }
}
```

I get 404 and this requestmapping doesn't fire no matter what request I pass. The controller is working as the other mapping "/endpointdoc" fires. 
There are no errors in the console.

Please advise.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `headers = "Accept=*/*"`?

how about something like:
`@PostMapping("/webservice/userDetails")`

Comment: I was confused what should be my Accept value. So I've set it as */* and setting the value as application/json in Postman

Comment: I believe that's why you're getting a 404, the RequestMapping is using the `header` field to help determine which mapping should be invoked, and it's not matching the string `*/*`. If you want to specifically state that it matches application JSON use:

`@PostMapping(value="/webservice/userDetails", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Your request mapping has `headers = "Accept=*/*"` which tells spring that it should only match a request to that controller method if the request header contains `"Accept=*/*"`

If you wish to only accept requests that have `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers defined as `application/json` you should use the `produces` and `consumes` properties of the `RequestMapping`.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/webservice/userDetails", 
method = RequestMethod.POST, // only match to POST requests
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,  // match Content-Type application/json
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)  // match Accept application/json
```

Comment: I don't find APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE in either of the MediaType packages as below:

`java.awt.PageAttributes
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser
org.springframework.http   // which is where it should have been
com.google.common.net`

Comment: interesting, it should be in `org.springframework.http` but if not, you can always just use the string "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution guys :

I had to set a property for CSRF handler to allow this URL. OR, U may set a CSRF to this POJO :)

Cheers!